# MySql sorted subquery with group by in main query

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm developing a simple message system for my website. Here's an image of how the messages table works:

[Picture of the MySql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqX1.png)

What I had in mind is to use a subquery and then use GROUP BY to get only the last message for every person that was sent to, in this case, the user 1. This is the first query:

```
SELECT m.user_id as user_id, u.username as username, u.avatar as avatar, m.message_id as messsage_id, m.message as message, m.date as read_date 
FROM users_messages m 
INNER JOIN users u 
ON u.user_id = m.sender_id 
WHERE m.receiver_id = 1 
ORDER BY message_id DESC
```

Some data is from another table, but it isn't relevant. This query returns this result, which is expected:

[Image with the results of the first query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEBwt.png)

I made the messages descriptive so you can see what's going on more clearly. Now, here comes the weird part. As you can see, the messages are sorted by message ID, so the comments are sorted from new to old. All good here. However, when I expecute the following query...

```
SELECT q.user_id, q.username, q.avatar, q.message, q.read_date
FROM (SELECT u.user_id as user_id, u.username as username, u.avatar as avatar, m.message_id as messsage_id, m.message as message, m.date as read_date 
      FROM users_messages m 
      INNER JOIN users u 
      ON u.user_id = m.sender_id
      WHERE m.receiver_id = 1 
      ORDER BY message_id DESC) AS q
GROUP BY user_id
```

This should group the messages by user, so only the first one (the newest one in this case) should show up. However, this isn't the case. It ALWAYS returns the first messages for everyone, as seen in the following picture:

[Picture with the results that make no sense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0GbF.png)

I'm really, really confused about this, and I can't find anything that helps me fix it.

Comment: No pictures thanks. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the `GROUP BY`, which selects an arbitrary result from the set you give it. I think you should be able to get the result you want by changing your first query:

```
SELECT u.user_id as user_id, u.username as username, u.avatar as avatar, m.message_id as message_id, m.message as message, m.date as read_date 
FROM users_messages m 
INNER JOIN users u 
ON u.user_id = m.sender_id 
WHERE m.receiver_id = 1 AND 
  m.message_id = (SELECT MAX(message_id) 
                  FROM users_messages m1 
                  WHERE m1.sender_id = u.user_id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me!! I'm still a little new, and I didn't know about the MAX() function.

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help.